# Не вызывается addButtonAction

Tags: java, javafx

Есть один FXML файл "sample.fxml" код ниже:

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
       <?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
       <?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
       <?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
       <?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
```

```
  <ImageView fx:id="lock" fitHeight="32.0" fitWidth="32.0" layoutX="292.0" onMousePressed="#lockButtonAction" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
     <image>
        <Image url="@res/images/iconfinder_lock_285646.png" />
     </image>
  </ImageView>
   <ImageView fx:id="close" fitHeight="32.0" fitWidth="32.0" layoutX="320.0" onMousePressed="#closeButtonAction" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
       <image>
           <Image url="@res/images/iconfinder_sign-error_299045.png" />
       </image>
   </ImageView>
   <ImageView fx:id="add"  fitHeight="32.0" fitWidth="32.0" layoutY="177.0" onMousePressed="#addButtonAction" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
       <image>
           <Image url="@res/images/iconfinder_sign-add_299068.png" />
       </image>
   </ImageView>
  <Label fx:id="time" contentDisplay="TOP" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="8.0" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="208.0" text="00:00:00" textFill="WHITE">
     <font>
        <Font name="Segoe UI Bold" size="51.0" />
     </font>
  </Label>
  <Label fx:id="more" layoutX="36.0" layoutY="185.0" text="More" textFill="#fffefe">
     <font>
        <Font name="Segoe UI" size="17.0" />
     </font></Label>
```

Есть класс "Controller" код ниже:

```
public class Controller {
@FXML private Pane pane;
@FXML private Label time;
@FXML private static Label more;
@FXML private static ImageView add;
@FXML private static ImageView close;
@FXML private static ImageView lock;
@FXML private Label percents;
private boolean ToTop = false;
private int minute;
private int hour;
private int second;
private boolean AddState = true;

public static void awake()  {

    if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        displayTray("Widget enabled");
    } else {
        System.err.println("System tray not supported!");
    }

}

private static void displayTray(String caption) {
    SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("icon.png");
    TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Tray Demo");
    trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
    trayIcon.setToolTip("System tray icon demo");
    try {
        tray.add(trayIcon);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    trayIcon.displayMessage(caption, "Thank you for using", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
}

@FXML
public synchronized void initialize() {

    Timeline clock = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> {
        second = LocalDateTime.now().getSecond();
        minute = LocalDateTime.now().getMinute();
        hour = LocalDateTime.now().getHour();
        String str = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hour,minute, second);
        time.setText(str);
    }),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1))
    );
    clock.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    clock.play();
}

public static void makeTransition(boolean state){
    if (state){
        add.setLayoutY(551);
        lock.setLayoutX(456);
        close.setLayoutX(489);
        more.setLayoutY(558);
        more.setText("Fewer");
        stage.setHeight(522);
        stage.setWidth(583);

    }else{
        add.setLayoutY(177);
        lock.setLayoutX(292);
        close.setLayoutX(320);
        more.setLayoutY(185);
        more.setText("More");
        stage.setHeight(210);
        stage.setWidth(350);
    }
}
@FXML
private void addButtonAction(){
    if (AddState){
        makeTransition(false);
        AddState = false;
    }else{
        makeTransition(true);
        AddState = true;
    }
}
    @FXML
     private void closeButtonAction(){
    alert();
}
@FXML
private void lockButtonAction() throws IOException {
    if (ToTop){
        ToTop = false;
    }else{
        ToTop = true;
    }
    Block(ToTop);
}

private void Block(boolean state) {
    stage.setAlwaysOnTop(state);
    if(state){
        Main.setMoveWindow(false);
    }else{
        Main.setMoveWindow(true);
    }

}
public void alert(){

    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION,"", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);  //new alert object
    alert.setTitle("Exit?");
    alert.setContentText("Are you sure want to exit?");
    alert.getDialogPane().setPrefSize(170, 100); //sets size of alert box
    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    if (result.get() == ButtonType.YES){
        displayTray("Widget disabled");
        System.exit(0);
    } else {

    }

}


   }
```

Проблема заключается в том, что по нажатию кнопки, как вы могли заметить под
fx:id "add", должна вызываться функция addButtonAction() котороя и изменяет 
размеры и положения элементов. Но вместо этого происходит ровным счетом ничего.

[image: Скриншот SceneBuilder]

В JavaFx я новый поэтому возможно в чем-то ошибся))

Отнеситесь снесходительно ко мне))

Заранее спасибо

Comment: В метод должно передаваться событие первым (единственным) параметром, что-то вроде `(ActionEvent event)`, но у вас событие к преса мышки, так что тип немного другой будет. Сцен билдер умеет показывать примерный скелет контроллера в верхнем меню, посмотрите какой тип события он сгенерирует.

Comment: Как я проверил в режиме отладки то оно заходит на эту функцию однако далее происходит чтото неясное. Кароче makeTransition()  как то чудит. Вопрос в том вот вроде все правильно написано, нет ни одной  ошибки но действие не происходит. Ломаю голову уже 4 день,  setLayoutY()  работает или нет , понятия не имею.

Comment: Уберите `static` у `fxml` полей